# return rows in a dataframe closest to a user-defined number

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a user defined number which I want to compare to a certain column of a dataframe.

I would like to return the rows of a dataframe which contain (in a certain column of df, say, df.num) the 5 closest numbers to the given number x.

Any suggestions for the best way to do this without loops would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 26):

I think you can use the [`argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.argsort.html) method:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": 1e4*np.arange(100), "num": np.random.random(100)})
>>> x = 0.75
>>> df.ix[(df.num-x).abs().argsort()[:5]]
         A       num
66  660000  0.748261
92  920000  0.754911
59  590000  0.764449
27  270000  0.765633
82  820000  0.732601
>>> x = 0.33
>>> df.ix[(df.num-x).abs().argsort()[:5]]
         A       num
37  370000  0.327928
76  760000  0.327921
8    80000  0.326528
17  170000  0.334702
96  960000  0.324516
```

Comment: Supposing we wanted to generalize this to giving us the 5 closest rows (when we have n inputs and we want to measure closeness to n distinct columns). Would you still  do it this way? If n=2 (say, x=0.75,y=5.0)  -- is it easiest to use "&"  df.ix[(df.num1-x).abs().argsort()[:5] & (df.num2-y).abs().argsort()[:5]]  ?   Thank you!

Comment: Did the pandas interface change? I need to use `df.iloc` instead of `df.ix` otherwise the fields are all `NaN`.

Comment: Ah I think the problem is with my df's index, it is not a sequence like `range(len(df))`. `iloc` however seems to work with both a "normal" index and my index. I'm not very experienced with pandas but this behavior suggests that using `iloc` would be more stable?

Comment: This is wrong. You need to do .argsort().index to handle cases where your index might not conveniently go from 0 to N-1.

Answer (score 4):

Kind of new to python and pandas but I would suggest this.

```
#make random df and get number
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':0,'c2':np.random.random(100)})
x = .25
#find differences and sort
diff = df.c2.apply(lambda z: abs(x-z))
diff.sort()
#get the index for the 5 closest numbers
inds = diff.index[:5]
```

`inds` would then have the index locations from the original df for the 5 closest numbers. Hope this helps!