# Closest values within common index

Tags: pandas

In this dataset *df*:

```
data = ['dog', 'cat', 'rabbit', 'elephant']
i = data*3
base = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 2), index=i, columns=list('AB'))
marker = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,1), index=data, columns=['marker'])

df = base.join(marker)
```

How to get the rows of column df['A'] with the closest value to its marker?

Went through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758023/return-rows-in-a-dataframe-closest-to-a-user-defined-number) but could not manage to extract rows per unique index.

Comment: show us what you actually tried, and what your expected output is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
np.random.seed(123)

data = ['dog', 'cat', 'rabbit', 'elephant']
i = data*3
base = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, 2), index=i, columns=list('AB'))
marker = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,1), index=data, columns=['marker'])

print (base)
                 A         B
dog      -1.085631  0.997345
cat       0.282978 -1.506295
rabbit   -0.578600  1.651437
elephant -2.426679 -0.428913
dog       1.265936 -0.866740
cat      -0.678886 -0.094709
rabbit    1.491390 -0.638902
elephant -0.443982 -0.434351
dog       2.205930  2.186786
cat       1.004054  0.386186
rabbit    0.737369  1.490732
elephant -0.935834  1.175829

print (marker)
            marker
dog      -1.253881
cat      -0.637752
rabbit    0.907105
elephant -1.428681
```

Sorting index by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) - reason is avoid `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` in last filtering:

```
base = base.sort_index()
print (base)
                 A         B
cat       0.282978 -1.506295
cat      -0.678886 -0.094709
cat       1.004054  0.386186
dog      -1.085631  0.997345
dog       1.265936 -0.866740
dog       2.205930  2.186786
elephant -2.426679 -0.428913
elephant -0.443982 -0.434351
elephant -0.935834  1.175829
rabbit   -0.578600  1.651437
rabbit    1.491390 -0.638902
rabbit    0.737369  1.490732
```

Subtract columns by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and get absolute values, last filtering by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `min` and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = base['A'].sub(marker['marker']).abs()
s2 = base.loc[s.groupby(level=0).transform('min').eq(s), 'A']
print (s2)
cat        -0.678886
dog        -1.085631
elephant   -0.935834
rabbit      0.737369
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

```
df = base.join(marker)
df['marker'] = df['A'].sub(df['marker']).abs()
s2 = df.loc[df.groupby(level=0)['marker'].transform('min').eq(df['marker']) , 'A']
print (s2)
cat        -0.678886
dog        -1.085631
elephant   -0.935834
rabbit      0.737369
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Have a DataFrame that is already joined `df = base.join(marker)`, i.e. without separate *marker* Series. Is there a way to get this on a joined df?

Answer (score 0):

for the dataframe:

```
                 A         B    marker
cat      -1.364769 -0.723230  0.069315
cat      -1.141256 -0.124800  0.069315
cat      -1.658259 -0.881559  0.069315
dog      -0.277469 -0.621357 -1.389664
dog      -0.854505  0.282091 -1.389664
dog      -1.000602  0.171808 -1.389664
elephant -0.673019  0.202090 -0.735848
elephant  1.729002 -0.052014 -0.735848
elephant  3.083791  0.623577 -0.735848
rabbit   -0.946095  0.536181 -2.455088
rabbit    0.644441 -1.476657 -2.455088
rabbit    1.614225 -0.806389 -2.455088
```

...single-line solution with the code...

```
df.iloc[df.reset_index().groupby('index').apply(lambda g: abs(g.A - g.marker).idxmin())]
```

...gives...

```
                 A         B    marker
cat      -1.141256 -0.124800  0.069315
dog      -1.000602  0.171808 -1.389664
elephant -0.673019  0.202090 -0.735848
rabbit   -0.946095  0.536181 -2.455088
```